# OpenVPN apt-get install hanging at 72% on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, dpkg, vpn, openvpn, 17.10

So I decided to try the new version of Ubuntu out and I was a little surprised to see that OpenVPN wasn't included by default.

I've tried to run:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

And it always seems to just hang with no errors given (see below)

[OpenVPN apt-get failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYL9.png)

When I inspect `/var/log/apt/term.log` I get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../5-libccid_1.4.27-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libccid (1.4.27-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pcscd.
Preparing to unpack .../6-pcscd_1.8.22-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pcscd (1.8.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Setting up libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 (1.22-2) ...
Setting up opensc-pkcs11:amd64 (0.17.0-1) ...
Setting up openvpn (2.4.3-4ubuntu1) ...
```

I haven't found any errors, so I checked the `/var/log/dpkg.log` and found:

```
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked opensc:amd64 0.17.0-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked opensc:amd64 0.17.0-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 install openvpn:amd64 <none> 2.4.3-4ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-installed openvpn:amd64 2.4.3-4ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status triggers-pending ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-20
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status triggers-pending systemd:amd64 234-2ubuntu12
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked openvpn:amd64 2.4.3-4ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked openvpn:amd64 2.4.3-4ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 install easy-rsa:all <none> 2.2.2-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-installed easy-rsa:all 2.2.2-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked easy-rsa:all 2.2.2-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked easy-rsa:all 2.2.2-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 install libccid:amd64 <none> 1.4.27-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-installed libccid:amd64 1.4.27-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked libccid:amd64 1.4.27-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked libccid:amd64 1.4.27-1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 install pcscd:amd64 <none> 1.8.22-1ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-installed pcscd:amd64 1.8.22-1ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked pcscd:amd64 1.8.22-1ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked pcscd:amd64 1.8.22-1ubuntu1
2017-10-22 15:40:36 startup packages configure
2017-10-22 15:40:36 trigproc ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-20 <none>
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-configured ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-20
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-20
2017-10-22 15:40:36 configure libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 1.22-2 <none>
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status unpacked libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 1.22-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status half-configured libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 1.22-2
2017-10-22 15:40:36 status installed libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 1.22-2
```

I'm kind of at a loss. I've also checked the journal and found no errors.

It does not respond to `ctrl+c` and I have to run clear it manually / reconfigure dpkg.

I've insured everything is up-to-date and have restarted, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is a FRESH Ubuntu 17.10 install.

Answer (score 2):

So - this definitely isn't a fix, however I booted a live version of Ubuntu 17.10 and found that OpenVPN installed without issue. Since this was a fresh install, I ultimately decided to just re-install the whole OS and start again. This appears to have resolved the issue. Side note - another random issue is that virtualbox would also not install, this was also resolved by reinstalling the OS.

I'd be interested to see if anyone else runs into this, if there is a less overkill option to try.

Comment: Had the same problem and eventually managed to install `OpenVPN`package without OS reinstall.

Comment: there is a reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1725525